# Type hinting: specify type as bool or callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Given a base class such as (pseudo-codish):

```
class A():

    def has_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
        action = getattr(self, 'can_view')
        if callable(action):
            return action(*args, **kwargs)
        return action

    def can_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False
```

And a subclass such as:

```
class B(A):

    can_view = True
```

How do I type hint this?

Mypy raises this error:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "bool", base class "A" defined the type as "Callable[]")
```

I literally have no idea how to go about doing this.